# Login osas script- any other solution rather than delete home folder

Tags: macos, security, permission

I have an osas script used to auto mount some network folders for AD users in our mac os catalina. whenever it tries to load, it asks for permission from the user,

[image]

and the only solution if the user has clicked dont allow, is to delete the user home folder by logging him out and deleting from an admin account, which is time consuming. I have tried giving permission from the security preferences to osasscript, but that does not help in this.

[image]

Is there a way to delete the security cache or preferences while the target user is still logged in?

Adding the tcc.db file
[image: the 2nd 1 for apple events]

Comment: OK - I'll get you started with the reset syntax. You might have to get into the console logs to determine which specific entitlement you are having rejected to craft a reset for this. without a graphical tool to walk people through exactly what you need them to do, often they can't self rescue here. Are you using an MDM to push config profiles by chance?

Comment: yes, i am using mdm to push configs. i had tried to reset using tccutil, but even after giving the root pass, it was not allowing me..i will give it another go and let you know, asking for bundle id :(

Comment: What is in the **AppleScript** _script_ that is being run by `osascript` and how is `osascript` being executed?

Comment: the script mounts some network folders, by telling finder..nothing big deal..helps user not to remember network paths

Comment: @user3439894 You are perfect for taking the AppleScript portion of this to the finish line! As you ask - every single small detail matters for this to work. How it's called, exactly what call is made - there are several ways to implement this for sure and it's not simple in the least.

Comment: @bmike, Thanks, however shine's comment fails to fully answer what I actually asked and therefore I'm out of here.

Comment: @user3439894, honestly i have no idea what the osasscript does, a log in trigger installs a jamf package which i beleive creates a launch agent plist in launch agents to look at a script file in /library/scripts..script as follows:

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/osasscript`
`set myname to do shell script ("whoami")`
`tell application "Finder"`
`activate`
`try`
`mount volume "smb:// path name..."`
`end try`
`repeat until (list disks) contain "pathname"`
`end repeat`
`end tell`

this is basically it...there are some more lines which is repeat of the same..but that's it..let me know if that helps

Comment: @user3439894 any more ideas to help?

Answer (score 1):

The command to reset these permissions is very briefly documented by Apple.

```
tccutil reset AppleEvents com.apple.Terminal
```

There is some great writing to explain how it works though, the hard part is figuring out which "bundle" stores which keys so that you can reset things and get users to see the initial prompts and make a better choice.

- https://eclecticlight.co/2020/01/28/a-guide-to-catalinas-privacy-protection-4-tccutil/
- https://scriptingosx.com/2020/09/avoiding-applescript-security-and-privacy-requests/
- https://gist.github.com/haircut/aeb22c853b0ae4b483a76320ccc8c8e9 (A comprehensive list of things you can reset as well as a script to "do it")

In your case, I would enable the Apple Event server as well - it's listed in your screenshot. If that fails, you'll need that Scripting OS X article - it's a gold mine of experience, guidance, example for the problem space you are in.

p.s. Good luck doing this - we have to push all sorts of these at work to reduce people needing to make granular decisions about all their software and most of the time, people are too busy to read what's being asked let alone pause and research and know what to do in a workplace. It's a bit more manageable at home...

p.p.s. We use [Apple Enterprise Connect](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/Kerberos_Single_Sign_on_Extension_User_Guide.pdf) for this sort of automatic mounting at work - it's superb but costs a visit from Apple Engineers. Other options are [NoMAD](https://nomad.menu/products/) and [JAMF Connect](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-connect/). Learning how to do this, though will be invaluable for you IMO. Getting kerberos tickets before you try to mount helps greatly in our environment to simplify other tools for mounting shares if we don't use `eccl` command line tool for the Enterprise Connect app.

Comment: the config script is pushed from jamf, which requires user variable to load a user specific home folder

Comment: I really want to help solve this. We’re a JAMF pro shop too..

Comment: thank you for your help @bmike, i will try these methods..i am not into the jamf, though i supplied the script to be pushed from jamf

Comment: @bmike-- i tried enabling Apple Event server also to the accessibility and file folder permission list, but that also didnt help...tried reading the tcc db and found one flag or value setting to  0 whenever someone clicks Dont allow in the prompt, if allowed its set to 1, for Ktccserviceappleevents, tried creating a configuration policy in jamf pro allowing access for apple events with receiver identifier com.apple.finder, but that also didnt help even though the policy runs fine..it doesnt change the tcc.db value...

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out a way to sort this out..but defenitely with the help from @bmike
instead of the command `tccutil reset AppleEvents com.apple.Terminal` I used `/usr/bin/tccutil reset AppleEvents` and that reset the Apple Events permissions for all apps. Even though i found it was com.apple.finder the binder, resetting for all cleared it.
thanks all..will create a script or a jamf config profile to clear this.